# I want to stop the animation of the button when the user clicks on cancel

Tags: ios, swift

How do I to stop the button animation if users click cancel?

```
@IBAction func facebookClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        facebookButton?.startAnimation()
        facebookButton?.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You will have to provide more information to get some help. Where do you run animations? what is the code that is running animations? All we can see is you have something called facebookButton and that has a method called startAnimation but we have no idea what is being done. Please make sure you put as much information as you can  in here

Comment: May I know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the animation from button's layer

```
 let loginManager = LoginManager()
  loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
    switch loginResult {
    case .failed(let error): 
      print(error)
    case .cancelled:
      print("User cancelled login.")
     facebookButton?.layer.removeAllAnimations()  // remove animation here
    case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
      print("Logged in!")
  }
```

Comment: How to understand users click cancel on alert

Comment: is this a default facebook button ?

Comment: i can't write alert code facebook login default show this alert yes default facebook vutton